# Java : Checking if string exists (upper case/lower case)

Tags: java, string

I am trying to compare a string in Java SE Eclipse that the user gives as an ID to a string in my Derby DB. The string the user gives is `textStudentID` and it is compared to the ID in the database. But it only compares exact case (upper case or lower case) string. I want to find the string even if it is in a different case.

eg. the user enters textStudentID = "abcd" but I want to check for "Abcd", "ABCD"...

```
    String id = resultSet.getString(1); 
    if(textStudentID.getText().equals(id)){
        exists = true;
        System.out.println("this student already exists");
    }
```

I tought of saving everything in upper case, but I need it outputted as the user gave it.
This code checks just fine but only for the exact case string.
How do i change my code, or what do I add to make it check all cases?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

use [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)):

```
textStudentID.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the two strings by having uniform cases (uppercase/lowercase)
Try the code below

```
((textStudentID.getText()).toLowercase()).equals (id.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:-

```
String id = resultSet.getString(1); 
if((textStudentID.getText().toUpperCase()).equals(id.toUpperCase())){
    exists = true;
    System.out.println("this student already exists");
}
```